# How can I access the ahoy method on the controller if I have another class that handles my tracking?

Tags: ahoy

I am using Ankane's Ahoy gem, and I am replacing some existing code.   I have existing "trackers" through out the codebase that I want to have feed Ahoy:

https://github.com/o19s/quepid/blob/main/app/lib/analytics/tracker/book.rb

How can they access the `ahoy` method that is defined in my controllers?